# Apache + passenger - /tmp permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am trying to run ruby on rails under passenger with apache2 under fedora 19 and I got this error in log:

> [Tue Feb 25 09:37:52.367683 2014] [passenger:error] [pid 2779] ***
> Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Unable to
> start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the
> following error during startup: Cannot change the directory
> '/tmp/passenger.1.0.2779/generation-1/buffered_uploads' its UID to 48
> and GID to 48: Operation not permitted (errno=1)

That directory (/tmp/passenger.1.0.2779) doesn't even exist. I think that problem is with selinux. I tried to solve it about 4 hours. Httpd is running under user apache and group apache, I tried:

```
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep passenger | audit2allow -M
passenger semodule -i passenger.pp
```

but still nothing.

Comment: Manually create this file "/tmp/passenger.1.0.2779/generation-1/buffered_uploads" and give full permission. Once Give a try.!

Comment: not working, /tmp/passenger.1.0.xxxx and xxxx is different everytime i run server

Comment: Your passenger running with sudo user?

Comment: I dont know, it's apache module and apache is running under apache user, so I think passenger is running under apache user too.

Comment: Once check apache user permission. Other wise give a try with super user. :)

Comment: Everyone has right to write to /tmp, I even changed owner of /tmo to user apache... As i write, problem is with SELINUX, but I realy don't know how to solve it :(

Comment: Why you not using Nginx Passenger module? it's pretty straight forward :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you should switch SELinux into Permissive mode at first, then try to capture the audit log from starting Apache to run your application.[1](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01)
Once you got the home page of your application, you can build your custom policy with the logs.

1. Switch SELinux into Permissive mode and clean audit.log

   ]# setenforce 0
    ]# rm /var/log/audit/audit.log
    ]# service auditd restart
2. Restart Apache

   ]# service httpd restart
3. Try to open your application with a web browser
    It might give more information about what is happenning when you application is running.
4. Make a custom policy module to allow these actions

   ]# mkdir work
   ]# cd work
   ]# grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M passenger
   ]# ls
   passenger.pp   passenger.te
5. Load postgrey policy module using the 'semodule' command into the current SELinux policy:

   ]# semodule -i passenger.pp
    ]# setenforce 1
6. Restart Apache

   ]# service httpd restart

References:
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error, with a startup error about being unable to create a directory that did not exist. (`logs`, not `tmp`, but same sort of thing) I, too, battled with it for an hour and couldn't make sense of it. I created/deleted/chmod the directory many ways without success.

The fix for me was to change the parameters to `passenger-start`. Initially, my Docker container started passenger with:

```
exec bundle exec passenger start --auto --disable-security-update-check --min-instances 20 --max-pool-size 20 --max-request-queue-size 500
```

I removed all parameters, leaving just this:

```
exec bundle exec passenger start
```

At this point, passenger could create the log folder and file, and all was well. I could have restored the params at this point, but we decided they were not needed for the development environment so left them out moving ahead.

In hindsight, I have a hunch that I deleted the log directory while a file in it was still open, and the file system persisted that condition in some way. But that's just a hunch. Perhaps simply rebooting my Mac would have fixed it...